# Explore doing something or explore to do something?

Tags: word-choice

Would you say "explore doing something" or "explore to do something"?

For example,

> I explored to build a model for the data.
>
> I explored building a model for the data.

Comment: Please add where you have seen “explored to” and what interpretations of this phrase lead you to believe that this phrasing might be a correct.

Comment: I dont' remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Explored building" is the idiomatic way of stating this.

If it helps, think of it as a shorter version of a longer phrase, like:

> I explored **the idea of** modeling the data.